# Mapping json data to two different entities in java using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using jackson libraries in java.

I have following JSON structure.

```
{
  "Device": "1234",
  "By": "Manual",
  "Flow": 524,
  "Timezone": "Asia/Calcutta",
  "Timestamp": "29/09/14 15:50:00"
}
```

I have two Entities `DataEntity` And `TimeEntity`

```
class DataEntity
{
 String Devive;
 String By;
 int Flow;
}

class TimeEntity
{
  String Timezone;
  String Timetamp;
}
```

How can map above json string to different entities i.e. DataEntity and TimeEntity?
I'm using ObjectMapper Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate your classes with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true).

After that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataEntity dataEntity = mapper.readValue(json, DataEntity.class);
TimeEntity timeEntity = mapper.readValue(json, TimeEntity.class);
```